# Changing a CheckBox BackColor with no PostBacklike AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, backcolor

NET Intranet Website. With a Site.Master page and .aspx pages the usual asp net webforms.
I have these CheckBoxes as you can see in the picture. I am using JavaScript in order to change the background color to green once you click it without having to make a postback, like AJAX.

[image]

With My code, it works the only problem, only the box around the check gets affected by my code.Like you can see here.

[image]

But lets say I'm adding the property BackColor="Lime" in the aspx page..everything is perfect like so but of course the script doesnt work.

[image]

My asp code is:

```
    <asp:Table CssClass="GroupKPI" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <%-- Critère de recherche WP--%>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="labelList_WP" runat="server" Text="WP" CssClass="labelTitle" AutoPostBack="False" BackColor="Lime" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="Panel">
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="List_WP" runat="server" CssClass="CBList">
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell13" runat="server" CssClass="CellSeparator" Width="5px"></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell5" runat="server">
                    <%-- Critère de recherche WP CF--%>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="labelList_WP_CF" runat="server" Text="WP CF" CssClass="labelTitle"
                        OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" AutoPostBack="False" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="Panel">
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="List_WP_CF" runat="server" CssClass="CBList">
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell14" runat="server" CssClass="CellSeparator" Width="5px"></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell6" runat="server">
                    <%-- Critère de recherche SUBWP--%>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="labelList_SUBWP" runat="server" Text="SUBWP" CssClass="labelTitle"
                        OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" AutoPostBack="False" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" CssClass="Panel">
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="List_SUBWP" runat="server" CssClass="CBList">
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell15" runat="server" CssClass="CellSeparator" Width="5px"></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell7" runat="server">
                    <%-- Critère de recherche WP REGROUPEMENT--%>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="labelList_WP_REGROU" runat="server" Text="WP REGROU" CssClass="labelTitle"
                        OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" AutoPostBack="False" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="Panel">
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="List_WP_REGROU" runat="server" CssClass="CBList">
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell16" runat="server" CssClass="CellSeparator" Width="5px"></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell8" runat="server">
                    <%-- Critère de recherche ORGANISATION--%>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="labelList_ORGANISATION" runat="server" Text="Organisation" CssClass="labelTitle"
                        OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" AutoPostBack="False" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" CssClass="Panel">
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="List_ORGANISATION" runat="server" CssClass="CBList">
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <%-- Fin de la table KPI RANGÉ 1--%>
```

And My vb behind code placed in Page Load is:

```
     labelList_WP.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var checkbox=document.getElementById('" & Me.labelList_WP.ClientID & "'); if (checkbox.checked) {checkbox.style.background = '#9ACD32'; } else {checkbox.style.background = '#F3F6FA';}  ")
```

Note that i tried checkbox.style.background, checkbox.style.backgroundColor, checkbox.style.background-color, checkbox.style.BackColor with no success.

Also please note that I also tried to use something like this with no success on my checkbox.

```
    labelList_WP.Attributes.Add("onlick", "if ($(""#labelList_WP"").hasClass(""labelTitleChecked"")==true) { $(""#labelList_WP"").removeClass(""labelTitleChecked""); }  else {$(""#labelList_WP"").addClass(""labelTitleChecked"");}")
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, I've lost all my day on this..
Also the command debugger; within either one of my attempts doesn't ever pop the debug mode.

Comment: Just to confirm, when checkbox is checked you want its entire parent to turn green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
labelList_WP.Attributes.Add("onclick", "$(""#labelList_WP"").parent().toggleClass(""labelTitleChecked"");")
```

or, in your original code instead of setting `checkbox.style.background` set `checkbox.parentElement.style.background`.

Comment: This one worked, 

        checkbox.parentElement.style.background